# How to authenticate azure function for SharePoint online CSOM

Tags: azure-functions, sharepoint-online, azure-authentication

I have a C# code which I want to run once a day as Azure function. The function is supposed to connect to my SharePoint Site and convert some documents. [The code](https://github.com/saregbesola/PowerShell/blob/master/ConvertWordDocument2AspxPage/ConvertWordDocument2AspxPage.psm1) I altered a bit to fit my needs. The part I struggle with is how to authenticate while receiving the same context and avoiding refactoring my function/app. If I choose to use

```
AuthenticationManager am = new AuthenticationManager();
               
                using (var cc = am.GetSharePointOnlineAuthenticatedContextTenant(SiteUrl, userName, securePassword))
```

for authentication there is a problem because of the 2FA. They are some posts on the internet recommending the following approach, but it is working only if I ran the app manually.

```
using (var cc = authManager.GetWebLoginClientContext(SiteUrl))
```

From what I understood I probably need a certificate. However I can't understand how the SharePoint site will know about this certificate and grant the access. Also a lot of the examples are about using rest API which is fine but in my case this means refactoring the whole code. So is there a way to authenticate my function while not changing much of the CSOM code I currently use and not using REST API's and tokens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From what I understood I probably need a certificate. However I can't understand how the SharePoint site will know about this certificate and grant the access.

**Here is an sample code of Authentication of SharePoint Online CSOM using Azure Function class script called `csomHelper.csx`.**

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

public static class csomHelper {
private static string ClientId = "(Application ID)";
private static string Cert = "(filename).pfx";
private static string CertPassword = "(password)";

private static string Authority = "[https://login.windows.net/](https://login.windows.net/)(tenantName).onmicrosoft.com/";
private static string Resource = "[https://](https:)(tenantName).sharepoint.com/";
public async static Task<ClientContext> GetClientContext(string siteUrl)
{

var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, false);
var certPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME"), "site\\wwwroot\\&lt;FunctionName&gt;\\", Cert);
var cert = new X509Certificate2(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(certPath),

CertPassword,
X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable |
X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet |
X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(Resource, new ClientAssertionCertificate(ClientId, cert));
var token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
var ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);

ctx.ExecutingWebRequest += (s, e) =>
{
e.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authorization"] ="Bearer "` `+ authenticationResult.AccessToken;
};
return ctx;
    }
}
```

- In the above code, we have App ID as ClientId, certificate file name, password and the tenant name to get the wright login and resource URL.
- The line `var certPath` open the certificate file.
- The line `var authenticationResult` uses the `cert` to initiate an authentication flow to SharePoint. If this works, the application receives an access token that it can use to access SharePoint.
- The code block starts from `var ctx` hook up an event handler which will run whenever CSOM executes a request; it will insert the access token into the HTTP header so the request is authorized by SharePoint.

For more information, please visit this [article](https://bob1german.com/2017/06/24/az-func-csom/).

Comment: can you please tell me if this azure function is .NET Core based ?